# Working with dynamically created input arrays in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I have a dynamic form with the following fields

```
<tr>
 <td><input name = "qty[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "color[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "price[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "total[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

I can dynamically add as many rows as I want. What I would like to accomplish is having total = qty*price for each row with a click of a button.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified your HTML a bit

```
<tr>
 <td><input name = "qty[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "color[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "price[]" /></td>
 <td><input name = "total[]" /></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='total' /></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery code

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var trElems = $("#tab tr");

    trElems.each(function(){
        var qty = $(this).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
        var price = $(this).find("input[name='price[]']").val();
        var total = parseFloat (qty) * parseFloat (price);

        $(this).find("input[name='total']").val(total);
    });
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8AGx6/)

Comment: thank you. This is working exactly the way I want.  Curious, why did you add the second "total"?

Comment: oops, I din see your total.:)